# Hadoop Reducer not combining all map jobs

Tags: python, csv, hadoop, mapreduce

Linked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583242/funny-results-with-hadoop-will-having-a-single-input-file-cause-this

I posted this question about Hadoop, but have now narrowed my problem down a bit so am creating a more specific question.

I have created a Hadoop Map/Reduce job. It takes a CSV and reads it into a defaultdict,  imports two files (positive and negative words) and then performs sentiment analysis on all the text from the csv. It then outputs this results (which is collected by the reducer) and combines all the keys.

I can run it locally like this:

```
cat ~/Text/ListOfTexts.csv | python hadoop_map.py | sort | python hadoop_reduce.py
```

This produces the intended results without any problems. I then try to run it using Hadoop Streaming like so:

```
bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.1.2.jar 
-file positive_words.txt -file negative_words.txt 
-file hadoop_map.py -mapper hadoop_map.py 
-file hadoop_reduce.py -reducer hadoop_reduce.py 
-input /ListOfTexts.csv -output /OutputOfTexts.txt
```

This processes all the information but for some reason doesn't combine the results properly. I implemented a "count" variable to see how many documents it was scanning (there should be 1199). If I run *just* the mapper, I get two output files, with something like 630 in one and the 569 in the other (thus adding up to 1199).

However, when I then use the reducer with the same code as used locally, I only get the 630 counted. Additionally, not all pairs have been combined. This makes me think Hadoop is not combining the results properly. Does anybody have any idea why this is happening? I can post my code if necessary, but am trying to cut down on the word count here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up getting this fixed with a cheap hack

The mapper wasn't sorting the results before the reducer started working. I had methods like this:

```
if currentKey == key:
    do something
```

The problem was that this would be executed for some of the identical keys, whilst other keys weren't read in until later and so their processing replaced what had previously been done in this statement.

To fix this, every line of input to the reducer was read to a new default dict to ensure all identical keys were together.

This was why my testing on the local machine worked. Because I did this:

```
cat name_of_file.csv | python hadoop_map.py | sort | python hadoop_reducer.py
```

Hadoop wasn't doing the sort bit in the middle.

I'm still not sure though *why* this wasn't done automatically by Hadoop and as I said, my solution is a cheap hack.